# How to strip a tuple which is in a Python list

Tags: python, arrays, list, tuples

```
my_list = [(101)]
Output: my_list = [101]
```

If number of elements are more than 1 in my_list then i can run for loop and can strip the tuple from the list , but when number of element is one, then for loop also gives an error .Error :int object is not iterable.

Comment: my_list = [(101)] evaluates to [101]. For tuple use my_list = [(101,)]

Comment: lst2 = [(tt[:2],tt[2:]) for tt in my_list]

Comment: putting a coma after an element is not in my hands. User can enter either 1 element or n number of elements. So a method should be there which can work on either 1 or n number of elements in the list surrounded by paranthesis. @ArpitChoudhary

Answer (score 1):

Because single `int` surrounded by `()` has type `int`.

```py
>>> t = (1)
>>> type(t)
<class 'int'>
```

You can use `,` to make it tuple. (if it has only one value.)

```py
>>> t = (1,)
>>> type(t)
<class 'tuple'>
```

Comment: putting a coma after an element is not in my hands. User can enter either 1 element or n number of elements. So a method should be there which can work on either 1 or n number of elements in the list surrounded by paranthesis. @nobleknight

Comment: you can check type of element in a list. if it is `int` then add that element directly to the `output_list`, else if it is `tuple` then add each element of that tuple one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first element of list is tuple.

```
my_list = [(101)]
if isinstance(my_list[0], tuple):
    my_list = [i for i in my_list[0]]

print(my_list)
```

In case of single element, my_list will evaluate to what you expect